# Understanding securing Firebase code

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I'm thinking about trying Firebase and have spent the day looking at example projects and the docs and I seem to be misunderstanding something, probably because I'm used to server/client-side architectures where the "interesting" parts of the code would be server-side:

According to the examples basically all the code would be using the Firebase commands in the client-side JavaScript. But wouldn't that expose almost 100% of my codebase/logic to the public?

How do I secure my code in Firebase if all of it is visible to the client?

Comment: Noone has an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

***You reading this***

> [Firebase Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

***Or
try watch video this***

> [key to Firebase security Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI)

***And Article***

> [Firebase Security & Rules](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a)
>
> [Quick Tip Firebase Realtime Database security rules](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-firebase-database-security-rules--cms-27926)

Comment: You are misunderstanding what the OP means by "security". He is referring to security of code implementing business logic.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. Your answer is regarding the database, where there were already several answers on this site. My question is specifically about securing the client-side code / logic

Comment: I am sorry misunderstanding

Comment: No problem. Have a great day :)